# Was given a connection string for MSSQL to PHP PDO; Error: could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, pdo

Bought a biometrics device and was given a Connection String to connect the logs (from hardware) to the website we're creating.

I was told that it's easier to just use MSSQL rather than migrate the tables to MYSQL. I'm trying to do it but I keep getting an error:

"Connection failed: could not find driver"

I searched through the net what could be the possible reasons & solutions:

-I downloaded SQLSRV32, 40, etc.

-Configured php.ini, the following does not have semicolons (;) in it:

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
```

-I tried odbc but I think it's for migrating mssql to mysql.

Here's my MSSQL:
[image: MSSQL]

I hid the full file name since I signed some waiver for discretion stuff.

Inside the Employees
[image]

And finally, my codes:

```
   <?php 
    try
    {
    $conn = new PDO ( 'sqlsrv:Server=(xxxx)\\v11.0;'
        . 'AttachDBFileName=C:\\PROGRAMDATA\\xxxxx\\TEST.MDF;Database=TEST');

    $query = 'SELECT EmployeeID FROM TEST.dbo.Employees ORDER BY EmployeeID 
    ASC';
    $stmt = $conn->query($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    ?>
```

And all I get in my SQLServerODBCConnection.php is

"Connection failed: could not find driver"

I've been wracking my brains connecting mssql to my website, I searched through YouTube and even StackOverflow but I found no solution for this yet.

Comment: In windows, its most likely you need the Thread Safe versions ONLY i.e. the `_ts_` extensions. You would never install both at the same time

Comment: I removed the other versions except php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll and php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll, however, the system is still not working.